# MVC Null exception after deploying to web server

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, deployment

I have an MVC 3 application that works fine when running locally from visual studio,

There are two bat files that pre compile the application ready for deployment, when i run the bat files and upload the deployment folder to the web server a load of errors are thrown including a null exception error,

The error can be seen by visiting the following URL, i can also provide the full stack trace on a document if required, i didnt want to post it here as its so big.

[error can be seen here](http://www.planet-adventure.com)

I cant understand where the error is coming from as everything works locally, t seems these errors are being created when the bat files are compiling the application, has anyone had similar experiences after deploying an MVC app? can anyone offer any advice on what may be causing the problem?

Thanks

Liam

UPDATE=============

This is the GetTax method, this code has been thoroughly tested as its part of NopCommerce 2.2, the errors only occur after the solution is compiled via the BAT files which is again standard for building a nop commerce 2.2 app, am i right in thinking its got to be something on my machine that is causing these problems when the BAT files are ran and the code is compiled for deployment?

```
public virtual decimal GetTaxRate(ProductVariant productVariant, int taxCategoryId, 
        Customer customer)
    {
        //tax exempt
        if (IsTaxExempt(productVariant, customer))
        {
            return decimal.Zero;
        }

        //tax request
        var calculateTaxRequest = CreateCalculateTaxRequest(productVariant, taxCategoryId, customer);

        //make EU VAT exempt validation (the European Union Value Added Tax)
        if (_taxSettings.EuVatEnabled)
        {
            if (IsVatExempt(calculateTaxRequest.Address, calculateTaxRequest.Customer))
            {
                //return zero if VAT is not chargeable
                return decimal.Zero;
            }
        }

        //active tax provider
        var activeTaxProvider = LoadActiveTaxProvider();

        //get tax rate
        var calculateTaxResult = activeTaxProvider.GetTaxRate(calculateTaxRequest);
        if (calculateTaxResult.Success)
            return calculateTaxResult.TaxRate;
        else
            return decimal.Zero;
    }
```

Comment: Which is line 240? Also, just something I try when debugging deployment issues, have you tried recycling the app pool in IIS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The stack trace indicates that it's coming from the method `GetTaxRate` in `TaxService.cs`. I'm guessing this isn't anything ASP.NET MVC specific, but a deployment issue. It could be database permissions or connection strings.. you'll have to check what that method is doing.

```
Nop.Services.Tax.TaxService.GetTaxRate(ProductVariant productVariant, Int32 taxCategoryId, Customer customer) in c:\Nop 2.2 Source\just4fashion2.2source\Libraries\Nop.Services\Tax\TaxService.cs:240
```

Answer (score 1):

It probably has something do with a configuration mismatch between your development and production environment.

If you look at the top of the stack trace you see that is has probably nothing to do with MVC but with someting in your `TaxService`.

```
[NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
Nop.Services.Tax.TaxService.GetTaxRate(ProductVariant productVariant, Int32 taxCategoryId, Customer customer) in c:\Nop 2.2 Source\just4fashion2.2source\Libraries\Nop.Services\Tax\TaxService.cs:240
```

You need to check on which element the Null exception occurs. 
Things to check:

- Is productVariant null?
- Is customer null?
- Are there any other elements accessed in this function like a Repository or Factory that could be null?
- Are there any configuration changes between local and production like connectionstring, logging or security settings?

Comment: Hi thanks for the advice, im pretty sure there are no null values, wouldnt nulls produce the same errors on my local environment? im thinking it must be some type of configuration error, i have checked connection string and that works with an older precompiled version, so i guess that can be ruled out

Comment: Null values can occur in production with things like Dependency Injection (and a differing configuration). I would add if ( == null ) checks for all values and throw a more descriptive error message so you know what your looking for

Comment: Thanks again, ill give it a try and post the outcome.